# Odd behavior when extending Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, object, backbone.js

Ok I ran into this recently and I can't quite figure out why its happening. Can somebody explain as to why `this._views` gets "cross pollinated"? Code as follows:

```js
var layout = Backbone.View.extend({
    _views: [],
    addToViews: function(view) {
        this._views.push(view);
    },
    renderViews: function() {
        console.log(this._views);
    }
});

var view1 = new layout();
view1.addToViews('some view');
view1.renderViews(); //outputs array(1)['some view']

var view2 = new layout();
view2.renderViews(); //outputs array(1)['some view'] **incorrect!**
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ed4BH/1/)

This works fine:

```js
var layout = Backbone.View.extend({
    //_views: [],
    addToViews: function(view) {
        this._views = this._views || [];
        this._views.push(view);
    },
    renderViews: function() {
        console.log(this._views);
    }
});

var view1 = new layout();
view1.addToViews('some view');
view1.renderViews(); //outputs array(1)['some view']
var view2 = new layout();
view2.renderViews(); //outputs undefined **correct**​
```

[fiddle me batman](http://jsfiddle.net/KAVSC/2/)

Plain vanilla js implementation seems to work correctly as well

```js
var layout = function() {
    var _views = [];
    return {
        addToViews: function(view) {
           _views.push(view);
        },
        renderViews: function() {
            console.log(_views);
        }
    }
};

var view1 = new layout();
view1.addToViews('some view');
view1.renderViews(); //outputs array(1)['some view']

var view2 = new layout();
view2.renderViews(); //outputs array(0)[]
```

[you know we fiddle the js](http://jsfiddle.net/sHNfz/1/)

So why does the `this._views` saves state when we create a brand new instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you extend `View` (or any of the other Backbone classes), you are extending the prototype of the class. The prototype is shared among all instances of the class. This means that any object you set as a property of the prototype will be shared between all instances, *not* unique to each instance. So extending a Backbone class with a property that's an object or an array will create a shared reference to that object among all instances.

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325864/oop-javascript-isolate-object-within-class/6326478#6326478) for more detail on this issue as it affects any class using prototypical inheritance.

Comment: how would I go about fixing the behavior while retaining ability to define properties in "extended" object?

Comment: I would usually define this._views in the .initialize() method, similar to your second example.